# Pricing Per Customer with no plugins

Tags: magento2.2.4, pricing

I want to implement pricing per customer. I'm talking about tens of thousands of rules, and I'm considering adding every customer (5000+) to their own group, and uploading prices with a csv.

Other than really long reindexing times (which I have running on a cron schedule anyway), is there any good reason to not do it this way? This is built in Magento 2 functionality, so why are so many people using plugins that don't do as good a job?

Comment: Unfortunately because of how magento's tier pricing works I think you will have to create a new group for each and assign prices individually. Although assuming there could be some overlap between your customers you could try and group some of those customers into a single group and then split it out when they need specific prices

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion Magento’s customer group pricing functionality is not built for your use case.

Applying that many rules you will need for applying customer specific pricing will be extremely complex. Lets say a particular customer have a fixed price for a specific product, how do you plan to solve it? You will need to have a unique catalog price rule for that very product for that customer?

Not sure about how many products you have, but lets say you have 1000, then in your price_index table you will have 5000 * 1000 lines = 5 000 000, then for all those prices there will be a rule that will be applied, your indexer will probably never finish. The main problem here will not be the fact that the tables has 5 000 000 entries, the problem will be all the catalog price rules being applied.

An alternative solution would be if you would skip adding catalog price rules. Then you modify the products getPrice functionality to return a price directly based on the final price you want to set for that customer / customer group for that product.

```
class Product
{

...

    public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,  $price)
    {
        if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

            return $price;
        }
        $groupId = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();

        return YOUR_SPECIFIC_PRICE_BASED_ON_CUSTOMER_GROUP

    }
}
```

Furthermore you will have to edit it the same way so you get the correct price in the indexing tables.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks. Implementing that is a little beyond the scope of what I can do right now. Annowaves plugin looks interesting, so I'll either use that, or just have one column of pricing using the MAgeworx plugin. Magedelight has been useless, and won't issue a refund